# SQlite Integer Primary Key on Code First EF Core

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-core

How can I set "integer primary key" in code first to avoid getting not null constraint failed error?

I want my Ids to be auto incremented on data insert.
Id property is tagged with `Key` and `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`.

I can't change anything directly on database

Comment: Why do you get such an error in the first place? The `Id` property shouldn't be nullable. Post your code

Comment: It's not nullable. 
My code is for now just a model and simple insert.

Model:

```[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id {get; set;}
public string Name {get; set;}
```

My insert 
```public void InsertData(DbContext dbContext)
{
var user = new User();
user.Name = "Some name";
dbContext.Add(user);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
}```

It works fine with SQL server but with SQlite I get error

Comment: I already explained that you have to make the field auto-incrementing *in the database itself*. You *must* change either the database or your code. To use that configuration as is, you must add `AUTOINCREMENT` to the database field

Comment: But I'm asking about situation where I can't change anything directly on the Db. What can I put inside my code to make it work

Comment: You have to understand that autoincrementing refers to *the database*. `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` means that the ID is generated by the *database* but EF Core doesn't know how that's done. The only reason this code worked on SQL Server is because the `ID` field also had the `IDENTITY` keyword, which means it was auto-incremented by the database itself. If you can't do that in the new database *you can't use `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`*. You'd have to change that to `None` and create a new value in your code. How you do that is up to you. Use a counter? Read the MAX(ID)+1?

Comment: Without AUTOINCREMENT there are few good strategies that can be used in a multi-client environment (multiple threads making independent changes count as clients). `MAX(ID)+1` can result in duplicates if some rows are deleted for example

Comment: If the database is created by EF Core, integer primary keys will automatically be created as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` columns. If the database was created by something else, then yes, you'll need to change the database.